# Xamarin.ios app is crashing in iOS 11 - Exception Type EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)

Tags: xamarin.ios

This app is build in Xamarin Studio 6.3 (Build 864) crashes at one instance. However, it does not crash every time but after some 4-5 scenarios it gets the crashed. And moreover, we are finding the crash report only with iOS 11. In iOS 10 it is working fine.

Please find the Device logs below:

> Incident Identifier: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-9669-xxxxxx
>   CrashReporter Key:   f9b347e7d0fa5f1571ff3d0a8d91f0d5bb0d1224
>   Hardware Model:      iPad4,8
>
> Date/Time:           2017-09-26 16:12:50.8723 +0530
>   Launch Time:         2017-09-26 16:11:03.9085 +0530
>   OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.0 (15A372)
>   Baseband Version:    8.01.00
>   Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
>   Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
>   VM Region Info: 0x10 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4307550192
>         REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
>         UNUSED SPACE AT START
>   --->
>         __TEXT                 0000000100c00000-0000000100c04000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...p/xxxxxx]
>
> Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   abort() called
>
> Filtered syslog:
>   None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>   Thread 0 Crashed:

Comment: I have the same issue! Any solutions?

Comment: Same issue on my app, any idea?